# What permission should be set on the list to use Infopath

Tags: list, infopath, permissions

I tried to set full permision on the list for the user and the button to edit Infopath is still grayed out. What permission should I set for the user so he can modify the infopath form on the list, and to crete new infopath list.

Answer (score 0):

Set permission in site scope(for that user can access library):

> site actions -> site permissions -> Grant Permission -> choice user and select only the permission "Contribute - Can view, add, update, and delete list items and documents."

**UPDATE:**

Set permission in list(InfoPath):

> Library Permissions -> add user with full control.

this permission allow the user create new form library, create content type InfoPath, deploy form in list, and edit form in list or contente type.

> If your InfoPath have code and run in browser, unfortunate not will work because need Administrator approval.

hope this helps.

Comment: But when I tried to ad Contribute premii on to all Sitę nothing show to user with contribute premii on.  This user can ' edit a info patch form.

Comment: Sorry, try set full control site scope, and check form library: Go to Library -> Library Permissions -> click inherit permission.

Comment: Yes but in the site I have got a lot of Aplication, and I'm afraid that with full control this person Destroy Them.

Comment: Now I undertand the your scenario, then set user as "Contribute" in site scope for he can see the library, and full control in library where has a InfoPath.

Comment: I tried Everithing and In site the user Should minimal have got Edit permission to the site, and Design to the list.